# From XML attributes to data.frame in R

Tags: xml, r, dataframe

I have a XML that contains data like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<posts>
  <row Id="1" PostTypeId="1" 
       AcceptedAnswerId="15" CreationDate="2010-07-19T19:12:12.510" Score="27" 
       ViewCount="1647" Body="some text;" OwnerUserId="8" 
       LastActivityDate="2010-09-15T21:08:26.077" 
       Title="title" AnswerCount="5" CommentCount="1" FavoriteCount="17" />
[...]
```

(The dataset is a [dump from stats.stackexchange.com](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stats.stackexchange.com.7z))

How to get a data.frame with the attributes "Id" and "PostTypeId"?

I have been trying with the XML library but I get to a point where I don't know how to unwrap the values:

```
library(XML)

xml <- xmlTreeParse("Posts.xml",useInternalNode=TRUE)
types <- getNodeSet(xml, '//row/@PostTypeId')

> types[1]
[[1]]
PostTypeId 
       "1" 
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLAttributeValue"
```

Which would be the proper R way of getting a projection of those two columns from the XML into a data.frame?

Comment: When i download the file it does not seam to be xml... What is the encoding?

Comment: @Floo0 it's a [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) archive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `rvest` (which is a wrapper around `xml2`) you can do it as follows:

```
require(rvest)
require(magrittr)
doc <- xml('<posts>
  <row Id="1" PostTypeId="1" 
AcceptedAnswerId="15" CreationDate="2010-07-19T19:12:12.510" Score="27" 
ViewCount="1647" Body="some text;" OwnerUserId="8" 
LastActivityDate="2010-09-15T21:08:26.077" 
Title="title" AnswerCount="5" CommentCount="1" FavoriteCount="17" />
</posts>')

rows <- doc %>% xml_nodes("row")
data.frame(
  Id = rows %>% xml_attr("id"),
  PostTypeId = rows %>% xml_attr("posttypeid")
)
```

Resulting in:

```
  Id PostTypeId
1  1          1
```

If you take *Comments.xml*
with

```
data.frame(
  Id = rows %>% xml_attr("id"),
  PostTypeId = rows %>% xml_attr("postid"),
  score = rows %>% xml_attr("score")
)
```

You receive:

```
> head(dat)
  Id PostTypeId score
1  1          3     5
2  2          5     0
3  3          9     0
4  4          5    11
5  5          3     1
6  6         14     9
```

Comment: Very nice. Any way of filtering the rows? For example just adding rows with `PostTypeId` 1 or 2?

Comment: This is what i would do aterwards... something like `dat[which(dat$PostTypeId ==2),]`... You might want to use packages like `dplyr` or `data.table` for further data manipulation

Comment: Or you can take care of it in-stream and memory/time-efficiently (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a great use-case for the `xmlEventParse` function in the `XML` package. This is a 200+ MB file and the last thing you want to do is waste memory needlessly (XML parsing is notoriously memory intensive) and waste time going through nodes multiple times.

By using `xmlEventParse` you can also filter what you do or do not need and you can also get a progress bar snuck in there so you can see what's going on.

```
library(XML)
library(data.table)

# get the # of <rows> quickly; you can approximate if you don't know the
# number or can't run this and then chop down the size of the data.frame
# afterwards
system("grep -c '<row' ~/Desktop/p1.xml")
## 128010

n <- 128010

# pre-populate a data.frame
# you could also just write this data out to a file and read it back in
# which would negate the need to use global variables or pre-allocate
# a data.frame
dat <- data.frame(id=rep(NA_character_, n),
                  post_type_id=rep(NA_character_, n),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# setup a progress bar since there are alot of nodes
pb <- txtProgressBar(min=0, max=n, style=3)

# this function will be called for each <row>
# again, you could write to a file/database/whatever vs do this
# data.frame population
idx <- 1
process_row <- function(node, tribs) {
  # update the progress bar
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, idx)
  # get our data (you can filter here)
  dat[idx, "id"] <<- tribs["Id"]
  dat[idx, "post_type_id"] <<- tribs["PostTypeId"]
  # update the index
  idx <<- idx + 1
}

# start the parser
info <- xmlEventParse("Posts.xml", list(row=process_row))

# close up the progress bar
close(pb)

head(dat)
##   id post_type_id
## 1  1            1
## 2  2            1
## 3  3            1
## 4  4            1
## 5  5            2
## 6  6            1
```

Answer (score 0):

A little easier than the other answer:

```
require(xml2)
read_xml('Posts.xml') -> doc
xml_children(doc) -> rows
data.frame(
   Id = as.numeric(xml_attr(rows,"Id"))
  ,PostTypeId = as.numeric(xml_attr(rows,"PostTypeId"))
) -> df
```

1. no `rvest`/`magrittr` packages, only `xml2`
2. convert strings with numbers to numeric